# Chromecast mDNS burst slowing down PCs

Tags: networking, lag, mdns, multiplexing

Starting a few weeks ago, at seemingly random intervals, 3 of 5 PCs will lag at the same time for a few seconds to the extent where mouse and keyboard input is delayed and VoIP calls are dropped.

After ruling out a few potential root causes, I suspected that something on the network was causing it.

So, a few times, I ran a constant Wireshark capture, waited for the problem to recur, and found that a large number (~1,500) of the following packets were transmitted over ~5 seconds and at the same time that the PCs lagged:

```
No. Date    Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
1361246 13:11.3 16889.25912 172.16.100.29   224.0.0.251 MDNS    [427 | 442 | 475]   Standard query response 0x0000 PTR Chromecast-1440b1ad27c2e70400c69c7c7900ee49._googlecast._tcp.local TXT, cache flush SRV, cache flush 0 0 8009 1440b1ad-27c2-e704-00c6-9c7c7900ee49.local A, cache flush 172.16.100.29
```

172.16.100.29's MAC address vendor prefix is A4:77:33 which is registered to Google.

We do have a Chromecast plugged into a TV and a laptop (one of the affected PCs) casts BBC News to it all day but we've been doing this for months with no problems.

Can anyone advise?

I'm aware that there are known problems with Chromecasts slowing down networks at the moment (https://www.theverge.com/2018/1/16/16897426/wi-fi-google-home-chromecast-archer-router, https://9to5google.com/2018/01/15/google-chromecast-home-wifi-outage/) but the scenarios don't match exactly, if only because our Chromecast is in use when the problems recur.

**Update: 2018/01/18 08:36**

As advised by @Spiff, I have posted https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/googlehome/MmnsVnSxdQc/Hs-dkFuKAgAJ

Comment: Given that the recently-publicized problems and your problem both involve mDNS floods from Chromecasts, I think you should probably join those other threads and mention your case to make sure they fix it for your case too. It sounds like Google needs to issue a Chromecast firmware update that doesn't do this.

Comment: According to Google, the flood comes from Android devices, which will need a Play Services update, not from Chromecasts themselves. At least that's my understanding.

Comment: @Artem Russakovskii I believe that that is Google's stance but **a lot** of people in that forum post are disputing it.

Answer (score 0):

the recent "fix" that Google is sending is just a small part of the fix. IT is NOT going to fix the real issue. They are saying it is going to be Android patch - but I have verified the issue occurs EVEN when android device is not on Wifi network. The real issue is with Cast framework, specifically google home or Chromecast sending bursts of packets.. 
In the meantime, you can try following: Go to Google Home app on android or manage your chromecast via Desktop app. Go to settings. Uncheck the item that says "Allow other devices to control the casted media"